# What is the probability a random orthonormal matrix will be a rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, orthogonal-matrices, random-matrices

Construct an orthonormal matrix in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in the following manner:

- Choose a point uniformly on the unit sphere in $n$ dimensional space (can be done by sampling from an $n$ dimensional [isotropic Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991961/gaussian-distribution-is-isotropic) and then normalizing the vector).
- Take the plane orthogonal to this vector. This intersects the sphere in a lower dim sphere.
- Choose a point uniformly at random on this lower dim sphere.
- Repeat until you get to 1-d.

Now we have a set of orthonormal vectors (the position vectors of the points we chose). They could form a rotation matrix or [another kind of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524931/constructing-a-simple-2-d-rotation-matrix). What is the probability we'll get a rotation matrix? And what are the other kinds of matrices that this algorithm can give us?

Per the question linked above, we know for two dimensions, this probability is 50%.

Comment: Isn't it obviously 50%? You can just flip the sign of (say) the last column to convert between the two kinds of matrices (with determinant 1 or -1). And this choice of sign is what you do randomly in the last step.

Comment: Ah, nice. So an orthonormal matrix with determinant $1$ is always a rotation matrix?

Comment: Yes, and with determinant -1 it's a rotation composed with a reflection.

Comment: I see. Thanks. This is very useful info but not obvious to me.

Comment: It's nothing particularly deep; you can find it explained in many basic linear algebra textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Take the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

- Rotate the entire basis in any way you want, to send $e_1$ to the first point you chose. This is possible (for large $n$) because the $n-1$-dimensional sphere is connected.
- Keeping $e_1$ fixed, rotate the entire basis any way you want, to send $e_2$ to the second point you chose. This is possible (for large $n$) because the $n-2$-dimensional sphere is connected.
- Etc.
- In this way, you will be able to rotate the basis vectors $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_{n-1}$ to the first $n-1$ points you chose, because the $k$-dimensional sphere is connected for $k \ge 1$.
- There will be two antipodal points which are orthogonal to each of the first $n-1$ points you chose. In the last step, you chose one or the other of these points, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Either you chose the one which is the image of $e_n$ under all the rotations I described above (in which case your $n$ vectors form a rotation matrix), or you chose the other one (in which case they don't).

If your $n$ vectors do not form a rotation matrix, they will form a reflection matrix.